# Recyclerview disappers when EditText not in Focus

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am making an android app, it has an editText on the top and a recyclerview on the buttom.

**Every time when a user hit "enter" in the editText field, I will then make an API call with OKHttp and save the info I needed to a Singleton Class so my adapter can use it and update the list.**

**However, the recyclerview is not showing(updating) if the focus is not in the editText**

[image: Here is how it is working on my device]

**"V/ViewRootImpl: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed"**
It's showing this everytime when I click on the editText, I googled it and found out it might be the thread issues. The only place I interact with thread is the API request I made with okHTTP. However, the request returns and interpret the json file correctly.

```
    public Boolean makeCall (String parameter) throws IOException, UnirestException {

    // make the api call
    String completedLink = BASE_LINK + parameter;
    Future<HttpResponse<com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode>> response = Unirest.get("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=wat")
            .header("x-rapidapi-host", "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com")
            .header("x-rapidapi-key", "xxxxx")
            .asJsonAsync(new Callback<com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(HttpResponse<com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode> response) {
                    // decode the response body
                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    JsonNode node = null;
                    try {
                        node = objectMapper.readTree(String.valueOf(response.getBody()));
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    JsonNode resultNode = node.get("list");
                    List<WordItem> resultList = null;
                    try {
                        resultList = objectMapper.readValue(resultNode.toString(),
                                new TypeReference<List<WordItem>>() {});
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SavedInfo.getInstance().setResult(resultList);
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(UnirestException e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void cancelled() {

                }
            });

    return true;
}
```

Every time when I hit enter on the soft keyboard, my code will start making the API call

```
        mResult.setAdapter(adapter);
    mResult.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    mResult.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    mResult.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    mSearchBox.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

                        // show progress bar
                        hideProgressBar(false, mProgress);

                        mHomeText.setText(textView.getText());
                        try {
                            if (new HttpRequest().makeCall(textView.getText().toString())){
                                adapter.updateList();
                            }
                            else {
                                // showing error message
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return false;
                        }
                        hideProgressBar(true, mProgress);

                        // hide keyword when enter key is detected
                        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
                        if (view != null) {
                            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
    });
```

Also, one thing to point out is the Progress Bar(I set it to "VISIBLE" but not showing still)is not showing at all. I set a few places throughout my code, the Singleton Class and Http Requests are correct and return + save correct info.

Here is my updateList() in my adapter class just in case this helps

```
   public void updateList () {
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(SavedInfo.getInstance().getResult());
    notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Here is the my layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#F3F3F3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_word_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:text="@string/home_text"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchBox"
            android:layout_width="254dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="239dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="239dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/searchBox_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:pointerIcon="none"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_word_home" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/home_resultList"
            android:layout_width="409dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the data posts to recycler view before that has downloaded. You are trying to update the recycler view in the method `updateList()` which called after the request started but before it completed. That's also why the progress bar doesn't show - it's immediately gone.

In order to fix the problem, you have to trigger `updateList()` after the data has been downloaded. The good way will be to rewrite the `makeCall()` method, which accepts the second argument as a callback, so you can update the list.

Define the custom callback:

```
interface MyCallback {

    void completed(List<WordItem> result);
    void error(UnirestException error);
}
```

Rewrite making call a bit:

```
public void makeCall(String parameter, MyCallback callback) {

    // make the api call
    String completedLink = BASE_LINK + parameter;
    Future<HttpResponse<com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode>> response = Unirest.get("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=wat")
        .header("x-rapidapi-host", "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com")
        .header("x-rapidapi-key", "xxxxx")
        .asJsonAsync(new Callback<com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(HttpResponse<com.mashape.unirest.http.JsonNode> response) {
                // decode the response body
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode node = null;
                try {
                    node = objectMapper.readTree(String.valueOf(response.getBody()));
                } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                JsonNode resultNode = node.get("list");
                List<WordItem> resultList = null;
                try {
                    resultList = objectMapper.readValue(resultNode.toString(),
                            new TypeReference<List<WordItem>>() {});
                } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                // SavedInfo.getInstance().setResult(resultList);
                callback.completed(resultList);
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(UnirestException e) {
                callback.failed(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void cancelled() {

            }
        });
```

}

And finally pass the callback to `makeCall()` and refresh the list:

```
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {

        // show progress bar
        hideProgressBar(false, mProgress);

        // clear your list before call if you wish
        // updateList(null);

        mHomeText.setText(textView.getText());

        new HttpRequest().makeCall(textView.getText().toString(), new MyCallback() {

            @Override
            public void completed(List<WordItem> result) {
                updateList(result);
                hideProgressBar(true, mProgress);
            }

            @Override
            public void error(UnirestException error) {
                hideProgressBar(true, mProgress);

                // showing error message
            }
        });

        // hide keyword when enter key is detected
        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This method should be rewrited as well:

```
public void updateList(List<WordItem> result) {
    list.clear();
    if (result != null) list.addAll(result);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

After that problem should go away and also you have no longer need in the singleton class that holding your data.

By the way, there is the [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library which used in order to make api requests in an easier way. The retrofit is the best practice in the android community, so I suggest to try use it.